# Solving the following system of equation

Tags: partial-derivative, systems-of-equations

I was trying to solve the following problem

> Find the extreme values of the function $$f(x,y)=2(x-y)^2-x^4-y^4$$

My attempt-
$$p=\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}=4(x-x^3-y)$$
and $$q=\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}=4(y-y^3-x)$$
Equating p and q to 0 I get
$$x-x^3-y=0$$
and $$y-y^3-x=0$$
I have no idea on how to solve the above 2 equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We next simultaneously solve these equations to determine the potential critical points.

We have:

$$x-x^3-y=0 \\ y-y^3-x=0$$

We can write the second equation as $x = y-y^3$ and substitute into the first and get:

$$ y^3(y^2-2)(y^4-y^2+1) = 0 \rightarrow y = 0, \pm~ \sqrt{2}$$

We do not care about the four complex roots.

Next, substitute back into the original equation to find $x$ and this leads to the following potential critical points for test:

$$(x, y) = (0, 0), (-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}), (\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$$

Can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good introduction on how to find max or min (or saddles) for a function in two variables [here](http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/min_max/min_max.html).

Read that. If you still have questions don't hesitate to ask again here.

EDITED: the OP asked how to wsolve the equations. So...

You get two equations. You get $y$ from the first (for example) and you substitute in the second. You will get following equations:
$$
x-x^3-(x-x^3)^3=x
$$
this can be simplified and factorized in this way:
$$
x^3(x^2-2)(x^4-x^2+1)=0
$$
Now you can easily find the solutions can you? Those are just quadratic equations. For you to check the solutions will be $x=0, \sqrt 2, -\sqrt 2$. Then you can take your $x$ and substitute them in your questions to get $y$. 
This should get you going and you should be able to finish your exercise.

Comment: I actually wanted to know how will I solve the 2 equations that I got.

Answer (score 0):

Solve for $y$ from $p=0$ and substitute in $q=0$. You will get
$$ x^3\,\left(x^2-2\right)\,\left(x^4-x^2+1\right) =0 $$
For each solution of $x$, find $y$ from $p=0$.

**additional work**
Here are the answers
$$x=-\sqrt{2} , y=\sqrt{2}  \\ x=\sqrt{2}
  , y=-\sqrt{2}  \\ x=0 , y=0  $$